# Javascript to set colour of html label back to default colour rather than assuming color black

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written the following javascript function to disable a text input field and grey out the associated label when a certain option is selected in a selectbox, conversley when other values are selected the text field is enabled and the label colour is set back to black.

It works, however it makes the assumption that the textlabel was black to start with which might not be the case, what is the easiest way to obtain the original colour and turn it back to that so it will work okya when the original color was not black.

Alternatively is there some other attribute of label that can be used to make it looked greyed out rather than explicity setting colour to grey. I know it cannot be disabled but is there something else that could be used.

```
function disableInput(selectbox, inputfield, disableValue) {

    select   = document.getElementById(selectbox);
    selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if(selected==disableValue)
    {
        document.getElementById(inputfield).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(inputfield+"label").style.color='grey';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(inputfield).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById(inputfield+"label").style.color='black';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a `style.blah` property to an empty string will cause the normal stylesheet to apply again.

Alternatively, you could define your styles in CSS and add and remove a class from the element instead of twiddling its styles directly.